# Allocate the first row of a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to allocate the first row of a group.

The input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
                   'col2': [1, 1, 2, 3],
                   'col3': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']})
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).first()
```

But I only get the first row back.

I want this output:

```
col1 col2 col3    first_row
A    1    value1  True
A    1    value2  False
B    2    value3  True
B    3    Value4  True
```

Comment: Does Your code defining `df` work, have You checked it?'

Comment: can you explain how you are calculating `first_row`

Comment: Where do the values in the `first_row` column come from? I.e. i don't understand the logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html). If the cumulative count is equal to 0, then it's the first row:

```
df['first_row'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).cumcount().eq(0)
```

[out]

```
  col1  col2    col3  first_row
0    A     1  value1       True
1    A     1  value2      False
2    B     2  value3       True
3    B     3  value4       True
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without grouping:

```
df['first_row'] = df.col1.shift().ne(df.col1) | df.col2.shift().ne(df.col2)
```

result:

```
  col1  col2    col3  first_row
0    A     1  value1       True
1    A     1  value2      False
2    B     2  value3       True
3    B     3  value4       True
```